# Adding right and/or left padding to AdView (Admob) hides the banner

Tags: android, admob

I have an app with ScrollView containing LinearLayout, Whenever I add padding (Right and/or Left) to the AdView or to the LinearLayout the Ads disappear, as if it doesn't fit into the width.

> I am testing on Galaxy S2 with Resolution 480w x 800h

**Code for the ad:**

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ad_area);
            adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "PUBLISHER_ID");
            layout.addView(adView);
            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

**Code for the layout**

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ad_area"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="50dip"
            android:paddingLeft="0dip"
            android:paddingRight="0dip"
            android:paddingTop="0dip" >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#EEEEEE"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textColor="#4c89c0"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#999999"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Try with relative layout as root.

Comment: No that doesn't do anything

Answer (score 2):

The ad needs 320dp width. Galaxy S2 is 480px with 1.5 density, so 320 x 1.5 = 480, or the full width of the device. So yes, if you add padding around the ad, it doesn't fit, and therefore AdMob won't show it.

Try moving the ad outside of the ScrollView that you want padding on.